# How do i resolve “Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.”?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, fetch

I am facing this issue in react native but it works in the react dom.
Also, I am not using middleware except react navigation middleware which is required by the react navigation to be integrated into redux.
What i am trying to do is to send phone and password to action which will fetch the token and save to redux store after which i also want to retrieve it for token authentication

**Store**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import AppReducer from './src/reducers';
import { AppNavigator, middleware } from './src/navigators';

const store = createStore(AppReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Action**

```js
export const login = (phone, password) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    let body = JSON.stringify({ phone, password });

    return fetch('/api/auth/login/', { headers, body, method: 'POST' })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status < 500) {
          return res.json().then(data => {
            return { status: res.status, data };
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Server Error!');
          throw res;
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL', data: res.data });
          return res.data;
        } else if (res.status === 403 || res.status === 401) {
          dispatch({ type: 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR', data: res.data });
          throw res.data;
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', data: res.data });
          throw res.data;
        }
      });
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { RootNavigator } from '../navigators';

// Start with two routes: The Main screen, with the Login screen on top.
const firstAction = RootNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main');
const tempNavState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const secondAction = RootNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login');
const initialNavState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  secondAction,
  tempNavState
);

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Login':
      nextState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.back(),
        state
      );
      break;
    case 'Logout':
      nextState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }),
        state
      );
      break;
    default:
      nextState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
  }

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
}

const initialAuthState = {
  token: null,
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: true,
  user: null,
  errors: {}
};

function auth(state = initialAuthState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_LOADING':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };

    case 'USER_LOADED':
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.user
      };

    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL':
    case 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL':
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.token,
        ...action.data,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        errors: null
      };

    case 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR':
    case 'LOGIN_FAILED':
    case 'REGISTRATION_FAILED':
    case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESSFUL':
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: action.data,
        token: null,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false
      };

    case 'Login':
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true };
    case 'Logout':
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  nav,
  auth
});

export default AppReducer;
```

**LoginPage**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { login } from '../actions/auth';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  }
});

class LoginPage extends Component {
  state = {
    phone: '',
    password: ''
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.phone);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, width: 100 }}
          placeholder="Enter phone number"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ phone: text })}
          value={this.state.phone}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, width: 100 }}
          placeholder="Enter passoword"
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        {this.props.errors.length > 0 &&
          this.props.errors.map(error => (
            <Text key={error.field}>{error.message}</Text>
          ))}
        <Button
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.login(this.state.phone, this.state.password)
          }
          title="Log in"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Log In'
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  let errors = [];
  if (state.auth.errors) {
    errors = Object.keys(state.auth.errors).map(field => {
      return { field, message: state.auth.errors[field] };
    });
  }
  return {
    errors,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  };
};

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
//   return {
//     login: (phone, password) => {
//       return dispatch(auth.login(phone, password));
//     }
//   };
// };
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: This should not work on ReactDOM since you are making async operations in your action creator hence returning a function not an object as stated in the error. This is where `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` comes in the stage. They handle those kind of situations. So, I wonder how this works on ReactDOM without using any middleware?

Comment: Is it possible to make it work without using middleware, any how?

Comment: No, it is not possible. If you don't want to use an external library then you should provide a custom middleware and teach your store how to handle those kind of situations. Simply, this is what redux-thunk does.

Comment: Thanks! I understood this issue now

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problem is that you do not use any redux middlewares that can allow you to write an action creator that return a function.

Right now, if you are not using redux middleware, you can only return an action like this

```
function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}
```

Try Redux-thunk library.

```
npm install --save redux-thunk
```

Now, in your applyMiddleware function, I think you can put that redux-thunk middleware and also your current middleware into it.

After you put it, I think it should not throw an error anymore.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes! it got resolved after adding ReduxThunk, thanks!

Comment: I was curious on how I can get it to work without using middleware

Comment: Again, it is not possible without a middleware. Even you wrote a three lines code to handle this, that code would be a middleware :)

Comment: I am curious why you seems do not want to use it? any issues with it? if you think that it can increase the file size, I am quite disagree because Redux-thunk is only around 10 lines.